# fetch value of two columns into a single hash variable

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

In Ruby on Rails, I am trying to fetch value from user_id and id column in rails. Now I am using the following code which concatenate two columns firstname and lastname

```
@profiles = Profile.all.map{|p| "#{p.users_firstname} #{p.users_lastname}"}
```

Instead I have to add the columns as two entries. Please help. Thanks in advance

**Update**

I want to get the values like this

@profile = ['user1_firstname', 'user1_lastname','user2_firstname', 'user2_lastname',....]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code will yield something like:

```
@profiles = [ 'Edie Pineo', 'Tierra Cardiel', 'Sparkle Berrey' ]
```

You're asking:

> Instead I have to add the columns as two entries

So, if I get it correctly you want instead something like:

```
@profiles = [ ['Edie', 'Pineo'], ['Tierra', 'Cardiel'], ['Sparkle', 'Berrey'] ]
```

... which is an Array of Array of Strings as opposed to your current code which is an Array of Strings.

If this is so, the following is a solution:

```
@profiles = Profile.all.map{|p| [p.users_firstname, p.users_lastname] }
```

#### Update 1 (unique values):

```
@profiles = Profile.pluck(:users_firstname, :users_lastname).uniq
```

#### Update 2 (unique values + disregard trailing and leading whitespaces):

```
@profiles = Profile.pluck(:users_firstname, :users_lastname).map{|array| array.map(&:strip) }.uniq
```

#### Update 3 (unique values + disregard strict equality for String & Integer)

```
# if you want string values
@profiles = Profile.pluck(:users_firstname, :users_lastname).map{|array| array.map(&:to_s) }.uniq

# if you want integer values
@profiles = Profile.pluck(:users_firstname, :users_lastname).map{|array| array.map(&:to_i) }.uniq
```

#### Update 4 (1-level array as opposed to nested arrays)

**...continuing from our [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139154/discussion-between-jay-ar-polidario-and-cr7) and to answer your *Update* question**

```
@profiles = Profile.pluck(:users_firstname, :users_lastname).flatten
```

*- tested working*

Comment: Use the others' answers instead which uses `pluck`; I believe it's faster and more efficient.

Comment: Jay, I have already done that. But sorry to say it does not eliminate the duplication. Do I have to assign the result to a Set. Is there any other option

Comment: @CR7 hmm I wonder why it didn't remove duplications. Perhaps some of the records have leading or trailing whitespaces? If so, please check my new updated answer.

Comment: I am checking this in two numeric field. So the issue not because of the whitespaces

Comment: @CR7 is one of the numeric field a String? and then the other one is an Integer?

Comment: @CR7 if this is so, then please see my "Update 3" answer

Comment: But actually both are integer values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139154/discussion-between-jay-ar-polidario-and-cr7).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `users_firstname` and `users_lastname` are attributes of `Profile`, you can skip map altogether:

```
Profile.all.pluck(:user_firstname, :users_lastname)
```

Comment: Thank you Ho Man. Is there any option to eliminate duplication

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck). Below will return an array of arrays with each nested array containing the firstname and the lastname.

```
Profile.pluck(:users_firstname, :users_lastname)
```

If, as the title of your question reads, you want a hash, you can convert it to a hash with `to_h`. It's not clear from your question how you want the hash to be formatted

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
@profiles = Profile.all.select(:users_firstname, :users_lastname).to_a
```